# Repmat in Python v/s MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab

For a given matrix, I'm subtracting the maximum of each row from the row. 
In MATLAB, I'd do something like

```
Xm = X - repmat(max(X,[],2), 1, size(X,2));
```

For Python, I've been toying with variations of

`Xm = X - np.matlib.repmat(np.max(X,axis = 1), 1, len(X[0]))` but to no avail!

Where exactly am I missing out? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `repmat` is no longer necessary in MATLAB, and has never been necessary with NumPy. You can subtract a vector from a row, the singleton dimension will be expanded automatically ("broadcast" is the term NumPy uses).

Comment: @CrisLuengo: The keepdims flag solved the issue for me.

Comment: Ah, hood you figured it out! I was just typing that out in an answer... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python/NumPy, explicitly replicating an array to make it match another is not necessary. Dimensions of size 1 (singleton dimensions) are [automatically expanded in a process they call "broadcasting"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

For example, given

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[4,5,6,7,8],[7,8,9,10,11]])
```

you can write

```
X - np.max(X, axis=0)
```

The array returned by `np.max` has a shape of `(5,)`, which is compatible with the shape of `X` (`(3, 5)`). NumPy aligns the shapes starting at the last dimension, and fills in singleton dimensions at the front if one array has fewer than the other.

However, this process sometimes needs a little bit of help. Because `np.max` returns an array with fewer dimensions than the input, broadcasting cannot, in general. match up these arrays. For example, `X - np.max(X, axis=1)` doesn't work.

The best solution is to use the `keepdims` argument to `np.max`:

```
X - np.max(X, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

The other option is to add singleton dimensions using `np.newaxis` in indexing:

```
X - np.max(X, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
```

Comment: On that same note, I'm trying an element-wise matrix division of two 3x2 matrices. I have  X = np.divide(np.exp(Xm),np.sum(np.exp(Xm),axis = 1)), the 1st argument being 3x2, the 2nd being 3x1 and I want X to be also 3x2 (The 2nd arg being repeated to form a 3x2 matrix)

Comment: @Deepayan: `np.sum` is just like `np.max`, you can add the `keepdims=True` argument. Then the division will be able to broadcast.